# How to find the domain of $3^\sqrt{x^2-3x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am so confused on how to find the domain of this function $3^\sqrt{x^2-3x}$ without graphing it. I have no idea what to do in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)= \sqrt{x^2-3x}$ and let $g(x) = 3^x$.

The function you describe can be written as, $(g \circ f)(x) = 3^{\sqrt{x^2-3x}}$.

Since $g(x)$ has domain every number on the $x$-axis, i.e $x \in \mathbb{R}$, you need only worry about those $x$ values in the domain of $f(x)$.

A square root function has domain all nonnegative numbers (all positive numbers and zero.

In particular, we need the function inside of the radical to remain nonnegative. That is,

$$x^2 - 3x \ge 0$$
$$x^2 \ge 3x$$

When $x \neq 0$ and positive, $x \ge 3$.

When $x=0$ and negative, $(-x)^2 \ge -3x$, but any positive value sqaured is greater than any negative values.

Thus $x \le 0$ is in the domain.

In conclusion, the domain is $x \le 0$ and $x \ge 3$.

Answer (score 1):

One way to de-nest the conditions is this one.

1. $y\mapsto 3^y$ is defined fo all $y\in\Bbb R$, so you just want $\sqrt{x^2-3x}$ to exist.
2. $y\mapsto \sqrt{y}$ is defined only for $y\ge 0$, so you want $x^2-3x$ to exist and $x^2-3x\ge 0$
3. $y\mapsto y^2-3y$ is defined for all $y\in\Bbb R$, so you do not need additional conditions for $x^2-3x$ to exist.

Putting "all" the conditions together, in this case amounts to just one condition.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Think of this as the composition of $3^x$, $\sqrt{x}$, and $x^2-3x$. Which of these has a domain that isn't all real numbers? And what is the domain of a composition?